# String ('A=0) is appended to the HTTP GET URL

Tags: php, mysql, web

Some of our users had some intermittent error on our website (PDOexception). Upon checking the log, I found that the string String ('A=0) are appended to the HTTP get. This is weird, because we definitely did not code this and it only happens to certain users in different pages and also not consistently.

Error log below:
[error] 28960#0: *500749 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A=0'
        LIMIT 1' at line 4'

while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.202.1.135, server: xxxx.com, request: "GET /index.php/productdetail?pid=8473'A=0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxxx.com"

Note:
/index.php/productdetail?pid=8473 is correct URL without the 'A=0

Thanks for anyone who can give some insight on how/when the 'A=0 are appended.

Comment: This is a case where you need to search your code that sets the relevant query and debug it.

Comment: With the given information it is not possible to tell you why this happens. The only thing that is possibel to tell is that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections (you do not escape `pid` before using it in the query).  Because if you would do proper escaping then a simple appending of `'A=0` to a parameter would not result in a sql syntax error.

Comment: The main questions what cause the 'A=0 to be appended to GET. IS there some server setting that we can look into? Btw, we are using Nginx.

Comment: Even though we escape pid for the SQL injection , the pid will still be incorrect (something like "8473'A" instead of 8473) and hence the page is still not functional.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your code.  It's from a SQL injection probe.  More details can be found here:

[Strange URL containing 'A=0 or '0=A in web server logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867813/strange-url-containing-a-0-or-0-a-in-web-server-logs)

Within the last week, I have seen 150 such requests on different pages and from different IPs.  You can confirm by checking if the UserAgent matches the one in that post:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pt-PT; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Comment: And, apparently, a successful probe.

Comment: Just because the page doesn't function with invalid input, doesn't mean it's vulnerable to attack from invalid input. For us this was more an issue of who sees the error message - the developers or the browser.